# SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin canShareVia check whether WhatsApp is available

Tags: ios, cordova, share, whatsapp, ngcordova

Before showing a "share via WhatsApp" button, I want to check whether this kind of sharing is possible.

I'm using [SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) with the paper-thin [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/socialSharing/) wrapper.

As the "via" parameter of `canShareVia` is platform-dependent, I use following structure to determine the `via` parameter:

```
var viaByKeyAndPlatform = {
    facebook: {
        ios: 'com.apple.social.facebook',
        android: 'com.facebook.katana'
    },
    whatsapp: {
        ios: '??? ', // not working: com.apple.social.whatsapp
        android: 'com.whatsapp'
    },
    twitter: {
        ios: 'com.apple.social.twitter',
        android: 'com.twitter.android'
    }
};

// ... determine `via` parameter from parameters above

$cordovaSocialSharing.canShareVia(
    via, 'message', 'subject', null, 'http://example.com')
```

This is working for all these social networks on iOS and Android, **except for WhatsApp on iOS**.

Which parameter can I use for this? `com.apple.social.whatsapp` doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: did this ever work?

Comment: @SeanMC It worked a couple of years ago with an ancient version of Ionic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found **in the docs**, that parameter `whatsapp` should work, but for iOS9 a whitelisting is necessary for the `whatsapp://` url.

So I used `whatsapp` as via parameter and added following to the `*-Info.plist` file and it works like a charm. BTW the clipboard-hint needs the entry in the `*-Info.plist` as well. Without, the hint is not showing!

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>

  <!-- quite sure there are already other entries -->

  <string>whatsapp</string>
  <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

Comment: the docs don't mention putting whatsapp in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes, and doing so doesn't make it work